My htaccess file on xammp localhost is not redirecting
I am currently learning php and followed everything in the course. My htaccess file i created is showing error 404. I have read so many documentations by setting AllowOverride from none to All and uncomment load rewrite module. None of these worked for me. I am working on a windows 10 xampp v3.3.0.
Below here is my .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]

I also created a route array here
$routes = [
    '/' => 'controllers/home.php',
    '/listings' => 'controllers/listings/index.php',
    '/listings/create' => 'controllers/listings/create.php',
    '404' => 'controllers/error/404.php'
];


$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (array_key_exists($uri, $routes)) {
  require (basePath($routes[$uri]));
} else {
    require basePath($routes['404']);
}

I tried the following
-I added a <IfModule rewrite_c> </IfModule> and still got error 404,
-Added some text within the rewrite rule and i got a server error 500 which means my rewriteRule is working but it's not loading my index.php page
-My .htaccess is in a public folder including my index.php file.
Pls i will be glad if this issue is solved. Thank you

You redirect every single request to /index.php. Yet your $routes array shows other scripts that should work as controllers. You will need to resolve that discrepancy, most likely. Does a script index.php exist in the http host's DocumentRoot or not?

yes my index.php exists in my document root. For the controller files, like i said initially,  I'm just learing this from a course i just bought. And now i am stuck.

Next step would be to find out what is actually raising the 404, the http server (so on protocol level) or php (so your application logic). I suggest you either use a php debugger or simply add a few logging statements to your controller to find out if those requests reach your controller or are already denied by your http server.

Also it makes sense to take a look at "rewrite logging". A feature the rewriting module offers. It gives detailed insights into what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine. See the documentation for how to use that.

I have an error folder in my controller that echo '404 error' and that is what is displaying on my screen. I also have my php debugger and everything seems to be okay.  I think my rewriteRule in htaccess is not loading index.php. Pls how do i take a look at the 'rewrite logging'. I appreciate your help. Thanks

You contradict yourself. If you see that what the "error" folder contains (how ever that works, no idea), then obviously your controller script did get called. Which means that the rewriting rule does work as expected.

Did you try adding some logging output to your controller as I recommended? You say that you "have your php debugging". Fine. But did you use it? Apparently not ... And about "rewrite logging": as mentioned that is explained in the documentation. Did you take a look at it? Why not?

yes i did. I know it wont be easy trying to get a solution. I have some php files in my controller folder and the only thing it reads is the error folder that echo '404 error'.

OK, so if you receive log statements from your controller, then it is called. That means your issue has nothing to do with request rewriting. The issue is your controller logic.

Alright thanks I'll keep going with the course.
